# Firebase test lab Android Emulator or Physical device to update WebView version

Tags: android, android-webview, firebase-test-lab

Each physical device or emulator in the test lab has webView versions frozen in time.

For example, for Nexus 6 API 24 it's chrome version 58.0.3029.125 which was released in 2017.

Question: is there a way to specify WebView version or opt-in for a latest one?

An alternative is to bump Emulator to API 27 which has chrome version 70.+ which is not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test Lab does not allow you to specify a specific version of a package on the devices. We regularly update the device images with the latest packages, but you may see older versions for a period of time.